# Mapping with ggplot2 and scaling

Tags: r, mapping, scale

I am a beginner in R and i have to do a project in which I have to analyze some data sets.
I wanted to do a map of the total federal impact by state so here is my code :

I used to have this graph (attached) but i do't have anything when i run it after removing some null rows. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRGq7.png)

I did not get how to change the  scale of the total federal impact tax impact in order to have contrast by state.

```
# Install the packages needed 
library(maps)
library(mapproj)
library(tidyverse)

# Get USA map from maps package 
states <- map_data("state")
view(states)

# Adjusting name of variables for matching 
fedtax_data2 <- mutate(fedtax_data2 , state = tolower(state))
states <- states %>% 
  rename (state=region)

# Join both data sets by state and create a new dataframe
fedtax_data2 %>%
  select(state,total_industry_impact) %>%
  left_join(states, by = "state")

fedtax_data3 <- fedtax_data2 %>%
select(state,total_industry_impact) %>%
left_join(states, by = "state")


# Detect row containing null data and subsetting it 

filter(fedtax_data3,is.na(long))
 fedtax_data3 <- subset(fedtax_data3,state == "alaska" & state == "hawaii" & state == "grand total")

# Making the plot 
ggplot(fedtax_data3 , aes(long,lat)) + 
geom_polygon(aes(group= group, fill = total_industry_impact)) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) +
  ggtitle("Total federal tax by state generated by The industry") +
  coord_map()


Erreur dans seq.default(ranges$x[1], ranges$x[2], length.out = 50) : 
  'from' doit être un nombre fini
```

I was expecting something like this :

Comment: Your `subset` filters rows in which `state` is alaska *and* (`&`) hawaii etc., which are mutually exclusive, resulting in an empty dataset. Try filtering for alaska *or* (`|`) hawaii etc.

Comment: Thank you ! I successfully dropped the NA values however the map that I got is not enough precise. Do you know how can I change the scale of the "total_industry_impact" in order to have a contrast ! thank you in advance

Comment: Without data I can only guess. Maybe you've got one or two extreme values in *total_industry_impact* which flatten the contrast (relative difference) for the remaining states? In that case you could use a transformation (log or 1/x) to amplify differences in the "normal" range. Make sure to point out such differences to the reader, though.